# Mechanics: question about forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

Can we find the work done by the weight of an object? If not, why? When finding the net work done we consider all the forces applied on the particle. But is the weight not a force that needs to be considered too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can find the work done by the weight of an object. For example if a $1 kg$ object falls by $10m$, the work done is $F dS = 1 kg \times 10 m/s^2 \times 10m = 100 J$, a number that's exactly the same as the change in potential energy $mgh$ (which it must be because of the work-energy theorem).

Only subtlety is that this quantity is not usually called the "work done by the weight of an object", but rather the "work done by the gravitational field".

Comment: @ilovecupcakes I don't understand what you're asking. The change in total mechanical energy is, of course, also a change in energy. $mgh$ is an energy. Finally I don't understand what you mean by "resistance", there is no electrical resistance in the problem and it is unclear what the word means otherwise.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes if there are no other forces, then yes.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes in that case there are other forces involved, so the answer is "no". If you are dealing with an object in water, make sure it is actually moving in the direction of the force. If it is not dropping (i.e. its height isn't changing), then gravity does no work because work done is $F \cdot dS$, and the displacement and force are not in the same direction.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes if it's rising, the work done by the gravitational force is negative, because the gravitational force and the displacement are in opposite directions.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes that w.d that you mention *is* the work done by the weight. It is negative, note the minus sign in front of it.

Comment: @ilovecupcakes Can you give more details about what exactly the problem is and what exactly the book says?

Comment: could you reply?